# XSLT: Output value and don't get the child node's value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this source XML:

```
<Book>
   <Title>Harry Potter</Title>
   <editorial>M<previous>Sort</previous></editorial>
   <languaje>ESP<previous>EU</previous></languaje>
   <nationality>ESP</nationality>
</Book>
```

When I use the function:

```
<languaje>
    <xsl:value-of select="Book/languaje"/>
</languaje>
```

I obtain the next output: ESPEU and y want to have only ESP.

How can I remove all the values from a specific node `<previous>`?

Thanks for all

Comment: What programming language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression

```
<xsl:value-of select="Book/languaje"/>
```

selects all text content of the `languaje` element, which contains

1. a `text()` node and
2. a `previous` element with a `text()` node itself
3. and another `text()` node

You probably want the `text()[1]` node (1) and `text()[2]` (3).

---

If you can use **XSLT-2.0** or above, you can simply do this by using the advanced functionality of the `xsl:value` (optionally with a separator) which can handle more than one value at once:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Book/languaje/text()" />
```

---

If you are restricted to **XSLT-1.0** and therefore XPath-1.0, `xsl:value` can only handle one value at a time. But you have at least three possibilities:

1. Loop over the `text()` nodes of the `languaje` elements:

   ```
   <xsl:for-each select="Book/languaje/text()">
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:for-each>
   ```
2. Apply the standard template on all of `languaje`'s `text()` nodes:

   ```
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Book/languaje/text()" />
   ```
3. Apply the standard template on the `languaje` element in combination with an empty template for the `previous` element:

   ```
     <xsl:apply-templates select="Book/languaje" />

   <!-- And on the template level the following -->  
   <xsl:template match="languaje/previous" />
   ```

The output of all three approaches should be the same:

```
'ESP'+'' = 'ESP'
```